# ARMAssembly short-circuit program

Tags: c, arm

I am attempting to write a program in ARMAssembly language and I am having difficulties right from the beginning. I am trying to write a program that will do a short-circuit evaluation of the following complex conditional:
if ((x > y && y > z) || (y < z && y < x)). I understand that I to put x, y, and z into r1, r2, and r3 but I am getting confused by syntax and everything else. Assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why the MIPS tag?

Comment: rewrite it as a bunch of nested `if`s with simple conditions.

Comment: I thought that MIPS and ArmAssembly were rather comparable?

Comment: Comparable and very different.

Comment: How about running that C code through your favorite ARM C compiler (e.g. GCC) and looking at the assembly produced as a starting point?  Also, you should generally make more of an attempt to solve your own problem, and post what you tried, and explain why it didn't work, instead of just asking others to do the entire task.

Comment: I was just simply asking for a start. I was just learning a new language and got a little baffled by what to do.

Comment: MIPS: https://godbolt.org/g/8rJ2YQ ARM: https://godbolt.org/g/HRI8zx

Comment: We're not very good at starts, but excellent at finishes.  Can you not find compares and jumps in the ARM instruction set?  CMP?  b[condition] ?

Comment: start with the arm architectural reference manual for the core you are using, and a compiler...

Answer (score 1):

The way to solve these sorts of problems is to rewrite your C input such that each C statement corresponds to a single assembler instruction.

Here's the original C code:

```
 if ((x > y && y > z) || (y < z && y < x)) {
   true-action;
 } else {
   false-action;
 }
```

Here's the re-written C code:

```
   bool xgty = x > y;
   if (xgty) goto L1;
   bool ygtz = y > z;
   if (!ygtz) goto false-action;
L1:
   bool yltz = y < z;
   if (!yltz) goto false-action;
   bool yltx = y < x;
   if (!yltx) goto false-action;
true-action:
   ...
   goto done;
false-action:
   ...
done:
```

Translating this into assembler should be trivial.